# AlwaysOn alert metrics for Solarwinds

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014

Currently, we have Solarwinds in place for monitoring our servers. I would like to know if we are okay to leave the default metrics for AlwaysOn as is or do we need to increase that a bit. The reason I am asking is because we are facing issues with one of our environments where I do not see any issue with latency but then it is reported in Solarwinds and triggers an alert. Please find the current values below. I tried searching google if I could get a specific recommendation on what these values should be, but could not find one.

LATENCY THRESHOLD – 10 seconds
WARN LOG SEND QUEUE SIZE – 5 MB
CRIT LOG SEND QUEUE SIZE – 10 MB
WARN REDO QUEUE SIZE – 5 MB
CRIT REDO QUEUE SIZE – 10 MB

Comment: Put a call into their tech support - they'll be able to tell you what to do.

Comment: Are you talking DPA, Orion, or NPM? (Or another tool? SW has a lot of tools.)

Comment: I'd be very interested to know **how** they are obtaining the "latency threshold" value and I'm betting that's the one that is throwing a warning as the others are very straight forward. I have a theory on how they are doing it and if that's what is triggering the warning they will most likely need to fix their queries.

Comment: @Shaulinator: It is Solarwinds Orion and they use powershell queries to poll remote machines and get the data, so I am not sure where the problem lies, if I say it is a code issue then the same code is working fine for other servers and if it is a metrics issue or polling interval issue then what should I set that number to.

Comment: The latest version of SolarWinds Database Performance Analyzer has enhanced support for AGs. HTH